# How does indexSearchable works in Weaviate?

Tags: weaviate

I want to store an object and associate it with a vector embedding. So I am using the [Bring Your Own Vectors](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/quickstart/custom-vectors) approach.

I want to use some properties of the object to filter and some I don't. So I guess, I have to name these properties in the schema and set `indexFilterable` to `false` or `true` correspondingly.

I don't understand how `indexSearchable` works, but I am guessing I should set it to `false` in all the properties?

Bonus: Ideally, I would only say in the schema the properties where I want `indexFilterable` set to `true`, it would set other properties it encounters to `false` automatically.